# why i cannot get data from api ? my live data "test" value equal null. how can i solve this?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel, android-paging-3

why i cannot get data from api ? my live data "test" value equal null. how can i solve this?

source code: https://github.com/ElmarShkrv/ChioreRickAndMorty

## Paging source:

```
class HomeFragmentPagingSource(
    private val status: String?,
    private val gender: String?,
    private val rickAndMortyApi: RickAndMortyApi,

) : PagingSource<Int, Characters>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Characters>): Int? {
        return null
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Characters> {
        val pageNumber = params.key ?: 1
        return try {
            val response = rickAndMortyApi.getAllCharacters(status, gender, pageNumber)
            val pagedResponse = response.body()
            val data = pagedResponse?.results

            var nextPageNumber: Int? = null
            if (pagedResponse?.info?.next != null) {
                val uri = Uri.parse(pagedResponse.info.next)
                val nextPageQuery = uri.getQueryParameter("page")
                nextPageNumber = nextPageQuery?.toInt()
            }

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = data.orEmpty(),
                prevKey = if (pageNumber == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else pageNumber - 1,
                nextKey = nextPageNumber
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

## Repository:

```
class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(
private val rickAndMortyApi: RickAndMortyApi
) {

    fun getAllCharacters() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(null, null, rickAndMortyApi) }
        ).liveData
    
    fun getCharactersbyStatusAndGender(status: String, gender: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(status, gender, rickAndMortyApi) }
        ).liveData
    
    fun getCharactersByStatus(status: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(status, null, rickAndMortyApi) }
        ).liveData
    
    fun getCharactersByGender(gender: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(null, gender, rickAndMortyApi) }
        ).liveData

}
```

## ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: HomeRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _test = MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>()
    val test: LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> = _test

//    var test = MutableLiveData\<PagingData\<Characters\>\>()

    var filterValue = MutableLiveData<Array<Int>>()
    
    init {
        filterValue.value = arrayOf(0, 0)
    }
    
    fun getAllCharacters(): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response = repository.getAllCharacters().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            _test.value = response.value
        return response
    }
    
    fun getByStatusAndGender(status: String, gender: String): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response =
            repository.getCharactersbyStatusAndGender(status, gender).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            _test.value = response.value
        return response
    }
    
    fun getByStatus(status: String): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response = repository.getCharactersByStatus(status).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            _test.value = response.value
        return response
    }
    
    fun getByGender(gender: String): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response = repository.getCharactersByGender(gender).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            _test.value = response.value
        return response
    }
```

## FilterFragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FilterFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFilterBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()
    
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentFilterBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    
        binding.apply {
            viewModel.filterValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { item ->
                chipgroupStatus.setChipChecked(item[0])
                radiogroupGender.setButtonChecked(item[1])
            }
        }
    
        binding.apply {
            btnMakeFilter.setOnClickListener {
    
                if (chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked()
                        .isNotEmpty() && radiogroupGender.getTextButtonChecked().isNotEmpty()
                ) {
                    viewModel.getByStatusAndGender(
                        chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked(),
                        radiogroupGender.getTextButtonChecked(),
                    )
                } else {
                    if (chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked().isNotEmpty()) {
                        viewModel.getByStatus(chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked())
                    } else {
                        viewModel.getByGender(radiogroupGender.getTextButtonChecked())
                    }
                }
    
                viewModel.filterValue.value = arrayOf(
                    chipgroupStatus.checkedChipId, radiogroupGender.checkedRadioButtonId
                )
    
                findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false)
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

## HomeFragment: (which i want to show data)

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var homeRvAdapter: HomeRvAdapter
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()
    private val TAG = "Home"
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    
        viewModel.getAllCharacters()
    
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    
        setUpHomeRv()
        initAdapter()
        observeFilteredData()
    
        binding.filterIv.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_filterFragment)
        }
    
    }
    
    
    private fun observeFilteredData() {
        viewModel.test.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { filteredData ->
            if (filteredData == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "filterdata equal null")
            }
            filteredData?.let {
                homeRvAdapter.submitData(lifecycle, it)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun initAdapter() {
    
        binding.homeRv.adapter = homeRvAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
            header = HomeLoadStateAdapter { homeRvAdapter.retry() },
            footer = HomeLoadStateAdapter { homeRvAdapter.retry() },
        )
    
        homeRvAdapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            binding.homeRv.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
            binding.shimmerLayout.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            binding.tvHomeSearch.isInvisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            binding.filterIv.isInvisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            binding.retryBtn.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Error
            handleError(loadState)
        }
    
        binding.retryBtn.setOnClickListener {
            homeRvAdapter.retry()
        }
    }
    
    private fun handleError(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
        val errorStates = loadState.source.append as? LoadState.Error
            ?: loadState.source.prepend as? LoadState.Error
    
        errorStates?.let {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "${it.error}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    
    }
    
    private fun setUpHomeRv() {
        homeRvAdapter = HomeRvAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            homeRv.adapter = homeRvAdapter
    
            homeRvAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy =
                RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
    
            homeRv.addItemDecoration(
                DefaultItemDecorator(
                    resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.horizontal_margin),
                    resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.vertical_margin)
                )
            )
        }
    }

}
```

## when i change viewmodel like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: HomeRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    var test = MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>()
    
    var filterValue = MutableLiveData<Array<Int>>()
    
    init {
        filterValue.value = arrayOf(0, 0)
    }
    
    fun getAllCharacters(): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response = repository.getAllCharacters().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        test = response as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        return response
    }
    
    fun getByStatusAndGender(status: String, gender: String): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response =
            repository.getCharactersbyStatusAndGender(status, gender).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        test = response as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        return response
    }
    
    fun getByStatus(status: String): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response = repository.getCharactersByStatus(status).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        test = response as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        return response
    }
    
    fun getByGender(gender: String): LiveData<PagingData<Characters>> {
        val response = repository.getCharactersByGender(gender).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        test = response as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        return response
    }
```

it worked but i can't filter data why i get data this way but previous way i get null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second way doesn't filter, because when you call your filtering functions you replace the `LiveData` object held in `test` (the one you're observing) with a new one (which you're not observing). So your observer never sees the updates.

I haven't used the *paging* library, but I'm assuming your first way is failing because the paging is happening asynchronously. So when you first receive the `LiveData` from the repository, there's nothing in it (the page of results hasn't been fetched yet) so its `value` is *null*. And that's what you're setting as the value of `test`. A result should come in to that pager `LiveData` at some point, but you've thrown it away - you're not updating `test` with the new values.

---

There are a lot of ways to solve this (I feel like coroutines would be the easiest) but since you're already using `LiveData` you could try using [`switchMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).switchMap(kotlin.Function1)), which lets you create a `LiveData` that pumps out the results of other `LiveData` objects you switch between.

This works by having a `LiveData` which acts as your *control* - when the value of that changes, `switchMap` calls a function which returns a `LiveData` *source*. So basically, you need a control that holds *the current type of filtering*, and the function needs to *talk to the repo to fetch a pager `LiveData`.

Because that's not exactly how your `ViewModel` code currently works, you probably need to rewrite it a little. First let's get a filtering data object:

```
sealed class DataFilter {
    object All : DataFilter()
    data class StatusAndGender(val status: String, gender: String) : DataFilter()
    data class Status(val status: String) : DataFilter()
    data class Gender(val gender: String) : DataFilter()
}
```

So we're defining all the possible filter types, and the data each one holds. (For what you're doing you don't need this, you could use a single data class with nullable `status` and `gender` and handle it depending on what data is provided, but this is a more general approach that works for anything)

Then you'd have a private `LiveData` holding the current filter type, and a public function that lets you set it:

```
// in the VM again
private _filter = MutableLiveData<DataFilter>() // you could add a default value if you want

fun setFilter(filter: DataFilter) {
    _filter.value = filter
}
```

And then you wire up `test` as something that reacts to changes in `_filter`:

```
val test = Transformations.switchMap(_filter) { filter ->
    when(filter) {
        is DataFilter.Status -> repository.getCharactersByStatus(filter.status)
        is DataFilter.StatusAndGender -> repository.getCharactersByStatusAndGender(filter.status, filter.gender)
        is DataFilter.Gender -> repository.getCharactersByGender(filter.gender)
        DataFilter.All -> repository.getAllCharacters()
    }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

And that should basically do it. You filter by calling e.g. `setFilter(DataFilter.Status(whatever))` and the `switchMap` reacts to the change by calling the appropriate repo function, and using the returned `LiveData` as the new source of values for `test`. Since `test` itself is never reassigned, whatever observes it will see all the paged values piped in as filtering changes.